# Read URL parameter for Helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

There are Helpers who are responsible for adding Active classes to the menu.

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static string IsSelected(this IHtmlHelper html, string controller = null, string action = null, string status = null, string cssClass = null)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cssClass))
            cssClass = "active";

        string currentAction = (string)html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        string currentController = (string)html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        string currentStatus = (string)html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["status"];


        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(controller))
            controller = currentController;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(action))
            action = currentAction;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
            status = currentStatus;

        return controller == currentController && action == currentAction && status == currentStatus ?
            cssClass : String.Empty;
    }

    public static string PageClass(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        string currentAction = (string)htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        return currentAction;
    }

}
```

While standard URL parameters ("controller} / {action} / {id?}" are involved, everything works fine. But how to read the variables in the URL.

Is https://localhost:/Contractors?Status=false

How to get STATUS data

P.S. For those who later want to use Helper. CHTML

```
<li class="@Html.IsSelected(action: "Index", controller: "Contractors", status: "true")"><a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Contractors" asp-route-status="true">Clients</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RouteData` only contains values from extracted from the route. So unless you add the `status` parameter to the route (e.g. `/contractors/{status}`) you can't retrieve the value from the route data.

In this case it's a regular query-string parameter which you can retrieve from `ViewContext.HttpContext.Request`:

```
var status = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["status"].ToString();
```